# Do i need to check query executed or not?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

In model, when query executing  there will be a if condition that checks the query executed or not.
ie,

```
$result = $this->db->query($dataQuery);
 if ($result == FALSE) {
       $status = 0;
       $message = $this->db->_error_message();
 } else {
       //remaining codes
 }
```

Actually the if codition is needed or not? If query does not executed or not responding, The flow of program will be break.Then what is the use of  the checking?

My seniors following the style which I explained here.

Comment: I think its required for the `$status=0;` part and also to display what error has been encountered

Comment: are you following this method? :) or just execute the query and accept result.

Comment: Actually it depends upon the requirement.

Comment: Is `query` catch-able?

Comment: yes,When executing each and every query they will check whether query executed or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's highly dependent on the type of the query, if it's an `INSERT` query and it produces an error when the `error_reporting` is disabled, then the user can see some pretty error message instead of not seeing anything as well as this information can be written to log files for debugging later. If it's a `SELECT` statement, it also prevents some cases including unsupported data errors, but in cases when no rows are found it is **[highly suggested](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)** to check each result if it has returned anything at all.